# Is there a way to display an array returned from function

Tags: c#, arrays, arguments

I have a function that passes one array as an argument and another array which takes doubles from that array and is returned.... I get a "System.Double[]" output instead of the array and tried converting it to a string but that outputs another error

```
class Program
{
    public static double[] findNum(double[] arr)
    {
        double min = default(double);
        double max = default(double);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            max = max < arr[i+1] ? arr[i+1] : max;
            min = min > arr[i+1] ? arr[i+1] : min;
        }
        double[] array = new double[2];

        array.Append(max);
        array.Append(min);

        for (int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
        {
            min = min < max ? min : max;
        }
        return array;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(findNum(new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
    }
}
```

Comment: you are printing the object using `Console.WriteLine` which will print the return type of object which is `System.Double[]` in your case? if you want to print the items then iterate over returned array using simple iterator (like foreach or linq)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `double[]` into string using `string.Join()`,

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", findNum(new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
```

---

[`Console.WriteLine(string value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_) expect string value as a parameter, if parameter is of type array, then it calls `.ToString()` function. This results into printing name of the class which is default behaviour.

To print array elements one by one, you need to convert array into string. Here [string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) is helpful.

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
> collection, using the specified separator between each element or
> member.

Comment: @Nathan, Does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You want an extension method like this:

```cs
public static string ToString<T>(this T[] source, string format="{0}\n")
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var item in source)
    { 
         sb.AppendFormat(format, item);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This enumerates the array and applies the values to a string formatter and outputs the aggregated string.

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(findNum(new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}).ToString("{0}, "));
    }
```